# Time.local() uses unexpected time zone

Tags: ruby, time, locale

I am assembling my first ruby script, which is supposed to set up a wake up time for my computer (Kubuntu 10.04).

```
wake_h = 7
wake_m = 40

t = Time.now
puts "Current system time: #{t.to_s}"
t += 24*60*60 unless t.hour.between?(0, 5)
tvals = t.to_a
tvals[0,3] = 0 , wake_m, wake_h

wt = Time.local(*tvals)
puts "Setting wake up time to: #{wt.to_s}"
`rtcwake -m no -t #{wt.to_i}`
```

The following output is produced:

```
Current system time: Sun Feb 13 13:15:08 +0100 2011
Setting wake up time to: Mon Feb 14 07:40:00 -0100 2011
```

So apparently Ruby assumes my local time zone to be -0100, although the current system time yields another (correct) time zone of +0100. Probably Time uses a wrong locale (I need the time-zone for Germany) or there is a DST issue (we currently have DST in Germany). How can I check/set the local Time uses?

Regards, neradis

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html):

“A Time-like class that can represent a time in any time zone. Necessary because standard Ruby Time instances are limited to UTC and the system’s ENV['TZ'] zone.”

So that's why it's giving you -0100.